# Gcloud custom domain

Tags: google-app-engine, dns

I have a custom domain and I want to use google app engine to deploy. I spent lot of time figuring out how to make google app engine to deploy on my custom domain. For example https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/console/using-custom-domains-and-ssl makes it work to some extend. It redirects to google appspot. My goal is to make it stay at my custom domain. I already added custom zone to my app engine and changed my ipv4, ipv6 and NS for goDaddy custom domain. This still make my custom domain to redirect to ***appspot.com. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure custom domain on your app. In app engine -> settings -> custom domains verify, and configure your custom domain to map to app serving from *.appspot.com. Once configured use DNS info provided to configure DNS entries. I noticed this doesn't work as expected in flex environment. Which is in beta state (NOT RECOMMENDED FOR PRODUCTION USE). I have similar issue with nodejs app, custom domain redirects to appspot preview domain, though configured to spec.

Comment: Solution to problem, but removes SSL. https://support.google.com/cloud/contact/gae_flex_custom_domain

Answer (score 1):

I moved to AWS and it worked like a charm